# I need to recognize a url with a question mark using regex

Tags: regex, url

I need to recognize a URL with a question mark using regex,
 like this format: "http://www.xxxx.com?a=123"

I am using now this regex: 
((www.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+://){1}[_.a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9/_:@=.+!?,##%&~-]*[^|\'|# |!|(|?|,| |>|<|)]*)

How can I change it to recognize also a question mark ?

Thanks
SHahar

Comment: is the url already alone in a string or you need to find it in a more larger string?

Comment: Putting your question into [refiddle](http://refiddle.com/) shows that your regex already matches the ?, but only matches up to the 1 in "a=123" (likely because you didn't add a * on the last character class).

Comment: in larger string, this string can contain more than one URL

Answer (score 7):

You may use `.+\?.*` to identify ? in your URL.

`.+` -> Any Character at least one or more time

`\?` -> To match ?

`.*` -> Any character for zero or more time

You may use below URL to test your regex

http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: So how should look the whole regex ?

Comment: Above given regex .+\?.* is complete and enough regex for your need.

Comment: Hey buddy I need your favor. Can you please vote up my Answer.

To vote up the my answer you need to click up button in top left corner. Its current vote is 0.